# Changing data in a django modelform

Tags: django, django-forms

I get data in from POST and validate it via this standard snippet:

```
entry_formset = EntryFormSet(request.POST, request.FILES, prefix='entries')
if entry_formset.is_valid():
    ....
```

The EntryFormSet modelform overrides a foreign key field widget to present a text field. That way, the user can enter an existing key (suggested via an Ajax live search), or enter a new key, which will be seamlessly added.

I use this try-except block to test if the object exists already, and if it doesn't, I add it.

```
entity_name = request.POST['entries-0-entity']
try:
    entity = Entity.objects.get(name=entity_name)
except Entity.DoesNotExist:
    entity = Entity(name=entity_name)
    entity.slug = slugify(entity.name)
    entity.save()
```

However, I now need to get that `entity` back into the `entry_formset`. It thinks that `entries-0-entity` is a string (that's how it came in); how can I directly access that value of the `entry_formset` and get it to take the object reference instead?

Comment: The question is not clear. Where does the second code snippet happen? It would probably help if you posted more of your view.

Comment: The second snippet happens directly inside the `if entry_formset.is_valid()` block.

Comment: unrelated to your question, what is the reason for not using Entity.objects.get_or_create(name=entity_name)?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest writing a helper factory function for your form set so that you can customize the display widget according to the data. Something like the following:

```
def make_entry_formset(initial_obj=None, custom_widget=forms.Textarea):
    # these will be passed as keyword arguments to the ModelChoiceField
    field_kwargs={'widget': custom_widget,
                  'queryset': Entity.objects.all()}
    if initial_obj is not None:
        field_kwargs.update({'initial': initial_obj})
    class _EntryForm(forms.ModelForm):
        entity = forms.ModelChoiceField(**field_kwargs)

        class Meta:
            model = Entry
    return modelformset_factory(Entry, form=_EntryForm)
```

Then in your view code you can specify the widget you want and whether to bind to an initial `Entity` object. For the initial rendering of the formset, where you just want a `Textarea` widget and no initial choice, you can use this:

```
formset_class = make_entry_formset(custom_widget=forms.Textarea)
entry_formset = formset_class()
```

Then if you want to render it again (after the `is_valid()` block) with the `Entity` object already defined, you can use this:

```
formset_class = make_entry_formset(initial_obj=entity, 
                                   custom_widget=forms.HiddenInput)
entry_formset = formset_class(request.POST, request.FILES)
```

You can use any widget you like, of course, but using a `HiddenInput` would prevent the end user from interacting with this field (which you seem to want to bind to the `entity` variable you looked up).